# Extending MatrixPlot to complex-valued matrices

Tags: plotting, matrix, color, complex

I'm looking to plot a complex-valued matrix in a way similar to `MatrixPlot`. I know how to map an individual complex number on to a colored swatch: if `z` is the number in question, just run

```
Hue[Abs[z], (Arg[z] + pi)/2pi]
```

In other words, the norm of `z` is the hue and the phase is the saturation. I would like code which maps a complex-valued matrix onto a matrix of images, as described by the map above, in the same form as one gets from running `MatrixPlot` on a real-valued matrix. I know `GraphicsGrid` can kind of do this, but the output is very spread out / ugly.

Comment: `MatrixPlot[ Hue[Abs@#, (Arg[#] + Pi)/2/Pi] & /@ # & /@ 
  RandomComplex[1 + I, {5, 5}]]`?

Comment: You can also use `ArrayPlot` with a user-defined `ColorFunction`: `ArrayPlot[A, 
 ColorFunction -> (z \[Function] Hue[Abs[z], (Arg[z] + Pi)/2 Pi])]` (`A` is the matrix.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
a = RandomComplex[1 + I, {5, 5}];
```

The argument `array` in `ArrayPlot[array]` can contain color directives as mentioned in [ArrayPlot >> Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArrayPlot.html)
[image]

So you can use

```
ap1 = ArrayPlot[Hue[Abs@#, (Arg[#] + Pi)/2/Pi] & /@ # & /@ a, ImageSize -> 300,
 FrameTicks -> Automatic];
```

Alternatively, you can use `a` as input array and use the options `ColorFunction -> (Hue[Abs@#, (Arg[#] + Pi)/2/Pi] &)` and `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`:

```
ap2 = ArrayPlot[a, ColorFunction -> (Hue[Abs@#, (Arg[#] + Pi)/2/Pi] &), 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ImageSize -> 300, FrameTicks -> Automatic]; 

Row[{ap1, ap2}]
```

[image]

Although, it is not mentioned in the documentation, the first argument of `MatrixPlot` can also contain color directives. So, both methods above also work with `MatrixPLot`:

```
mp1 = MatrixPlot[Hue[Abs@#, (Arg[#] + Pi)/2/Pi] & /@ # & /@ a, ImageSize -> 300]; 
mp2 = MatrixPlot[a, ColorFunction -> (Hue[Abs@#, (Arg[#] + Pi)/2/Pi] &), 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ImageSize -> 300]; 

Row[{mp1, mp2}]
```

> same picture as above